# Выключение передачи данных android

Tags: android, java

Как в андройде отключить передачу данных мобильной сети?

Comment: Перейти в режим "в самолете"

Comment: Я имею ввиду как программно это сделать.

Answer (score 2):

Есть несколько вариантов, смотря для какой версии Android вы это делаете.

- 1.6-2.2:

  ```
  Method dataConnSwitchmethod;
  Class telephonyManagerClass;
  Object ITelephonyStub;
  Class ITelephonyClass;

  TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context
          .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

  if(telephonyManager.getDataState() == TelephonyManager.DATA_CONNECTED){
      isEnabled = true;
  }else{
      isEnabled = false;  
  }   

  telephonyManagerClass = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());
  Method getITelephonyMethod = telephonyManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
  getITelephonyMethod.setAccessible(true);
  ITelephonyStub = getITelephonyMethod.invoke(telephonyManager);
  ITelephonyClass = Class.forName(ITelephonyStub.getClass().getName());

  if (isEnabled) {
      dataConnSwitchmethod = ITelephonyClass
              .getDeclaredMethod("disableDataConnectivity");
  } else {
      dataConnSwitchmethod = ITelephonyClass
              .getDeclaredMethod("enableDataConnectivity");   
  }
  dataConnSwitchmethod.setAccessible(true);
  dataConnSwitchmethod.invoke(ITelephonyStub);
  ```

  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4304110)
- 2.3, возможно будет работать на версиях и выше, но автора точно не говорят :

  ```
  private void setMobileDataEnabled(Context context, boolean enabled) {
  final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  final Class conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
  final Field iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
  iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
  final Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField.get(conman);
  final Class iConnectivityManagerClass = Class.forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
  final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = iConnectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
  setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);

  setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, enabled);
  }
  ```

Дополнение:

```
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    switch (telephonyManager.getDataState()) {
            case TelephonyManager.DATA_CONNECTED:
                setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, false);
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.DATA_DISCONNECTED:
                setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, true);
                break;
            }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8962211)
   [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11224725)

Comment: Спасибо. Я уже пробовал Просто проблема. Я в java недавно.
Появляются ошибки.

Comment: ошибки справа пишутся... или в консоли... так не информативно вообще

Comment: @inc вы недавно в java и используете рефлексию уже? круто

Comment: Ошибки, это в смысле то что подчёркнуто красным.
мммм под какую версию анроида создавался проэкт?